# After data migration to Magento 2: system attributes missing

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.0.2, magento2-migration-tool

I migrated from Magento 1.6.2 to 2.0.2 with the official data migration tool.

In general, it worked. But I cannot modify any product (no field is displayed).
I suspect it is due to the fact that all the new system attributes (like category_ids) and the set of attributes "Default" are missing.

I just don't know why these attributes are removed and what to do about them.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After lots of hours figuring out why this happens I found out the migration tool is mapping some records by **entity_type_id**. But: If you don't have the same entity_type_ids as in the default installation it just cannot work as expected.

So that's what I did to align the entity_type_ids:

1. Carefully compare entity_type_id and entity_type_code of eav_entity_type table between M1 and M2.
2. Figure out all the tables where entity_type_id is a column. (Fortunately there's an SQL for that). Sometimes there is a foreign key with update cascade. Sometimes there is nothing which brings us to step 3:
3. Create the update SQL to switch the entity_type_ids manually in the main table eav_entity_type and other tables where no foreign key updates the id automatically. See here for my final list: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ByasBh_kQMC89pemDRv4c1eEX82cmtssrIv4aYBJdsM/edit?usp=sharing
4. Run migration
5. Edit product!

I know it is strongly **not** advised to update DB directly but I just don't know of another solution. I could have somehow fixed the data migration tool, but I didn't. :-)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. The price attribute is not present in my migration_default attributes.. The store is live, Is there any other way I can fix it.? Because going to the migration again and doing all the customizations from the start is really tough from this point..is there any other way?